# Correctly receive messages from button

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to correctly receive message from another window's button.Maybe I need to use hooks, but I'm not sure about this thing( that's why I'm asking ).So this particular that I want to do( but it doesn't work correctly ):

```
void CaptureTextWindow::Execute()
{
    BOOL bRet;
    vector<string> TextInWindow( ExecuteCapturingWindow() );
    while( !( bRet = GetMessage( NULL, hWndBut, 0 , 0 ) ) )
    {
        SaveResultToFile( "Message.txt" );
    }
}
```

So this what I want, if the button from another window( process ) is pressed, this program should save the something to a file, otherwise it should wait.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess what that code is meant to do...

Comment: You need to clarify a few points: Is this *other window* in the same process? On the same thread? How does this not work correctly? What's the expected result and the actual result?

Comment: `GetMessage` explicitly states that window has to be in the same thread. It also doesn't say the first argument is optional. Anyway, what specifically are you trying to get from the button?

Comment: Sorry, this code doesn't clarify, what I intended to do.So this what I want, if the button from another window( process ) is pressed, this program should save the something to a file, otherwise it should wait.

Comment: Unless the button's yours, the only decent thing I can think of is [this hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_callwndproc_wh_callwndprocret).

Comment: -1. Must downvote, because this concept is too bad. Also as pointed by Chris, you dont read documentation, so please delete this question.

Comment: Either inject, or use a get message hook. I already hate your program.

Comment: Thx for critisizing, I love all your comments :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect a button press in another process, you have to hook that process.  You have four choices for doing that:

1. use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to install a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook into the target process to catch the [`WM_COMMAND/BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message that is sent to the button's parent window when the button is clicked.  The message identifies the `HWND` and ID of the button that was clicked.  The hook **must** be implemented in a DLL so it can be injected into another process.
2. use [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to catch the `EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED` event when the button is clicked.  The hook callback identifies the `HWND` and ID of the button that was clicked.  The hook **should** be implemented in a DLL so it can be injected into the target process for better performance, but is not **required**.  If you do not use a DLL, the hooking thread **must** have a message loop to receive the events as they will have to be passed across process boundaries.
3. use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CreateRemoteThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to inject code into the target process and have that code then subclass the button's parent window using [`SetWindowsLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to catch the [`WM_COMMAND/BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message that is sent to that parent window.
4. use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).  Create an instance of the [`IUIAutomation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406.aspx) interface using the `CoCreateInstance()` function, then use the [`IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671534.aspx) method to get an [`IUIAutomationElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671425.aspx%2a) interface from the button's `HWND` (or obtain the button's [`IUIAutomationElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671425.aspx%2a) interface through other means), then use the  [`IUIAutomation::AddAutomationEventHandler()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671508.aspx) method to subscribe to the `UIA_Invoke_InvokedEventId` event for that button.

If you have the `HWND` of the target button, you can use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the button's process ID and thread ID.  You will need the button's parent window `HWND` (which you can get using [`GetParent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if needed) in order to use [`SetWindowsLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allow you to specify the specific thread ID to hook (and in the case of [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the specific process ID as well) so you can minimize overhead used in hooking.  [`CreateRemoteThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires the target process handle, which you can get with [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the process ID.

So, as you can see, what you are asking for is not going to be trivial to implement.  In my opinion (not definitive), the order of techniques from easiest to hardest, in terms of coding, would be:

1. [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) without a DLL (but at the cost of affecting performance).
2. [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).
3. [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a DLL.
4. [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because of the extra injection code and subclassing

Comment: Another - widely unknown - facility that provides the required functionality is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : How to get button name from HWND and ID. Like from Google homepage, I want to get name "Google Search", when I click on it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @grit639 buttons don't have names at runtime. But they have display text, which you can get by sending a `WM_GETTEXT` to the button's `HWND`. However, you mention Google. Web browsers don't use standard Win32 controls in their content UIs, for performance reasons. The only ways to manipulate browser content is via UIAutomation (if supported by the browser) or dedicated browser-specific DOM APIs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Thanks a lot!. Can't appreciate enough. Please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703414/setwineventhook-has-event-object-invoked-but-event-is-not-triggered-on-clicking . I am able to see button display text when I use SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, 0, WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); . But this gives me ALL element details. I just want the ones which user interacted with.

Comment: @grit639 you should update that question to include that detail.